# How do I "nest" modules in Verilog?

Tags: assembly, mips, verilog, hdl, vivado

I am  making a single cycle cpu that follows MIPS assembly instructions and am wondering how to clean up the schematic.  So for example I have several different modules instantiated together as shown by the code below.  Now when this comes up under schematic, all of the modules are their own block that can be opened up by clicking the top left corner.

My question is how can I link the modules so that my end result is something like this picture:[image]

I dont need the code of how to do that under my circumstance but a simple syntax of showing how to link different modules and "nest" smaller ones under larger ones.  If this is at all possible.

Thank you

```
module CPU_Wire(clk,clrn);

input clk,clrn;

//programCounter    
wire [31:0] pcinw;  //wire going from the multiplexer2 output to the input of pc
wire [31:0] pcoutw; //from pc to the instruction fetch input
wire clkw,clrnw;    //wires for clk and clrn
wire [31:0] pc1;    //wire going from PC to instructionFetch without the +4

//instructionFetch
wire [5:0] opw,funcw;
wire [4:0] rsw,rtw,rdw;  //decoding output wires         
wire [31:0] saw;        //need bigger wire for sign extension of sa 
wire [15:0] immw;
wire [31:0] immoutw;     //for immediate output
wire [25:0] addrw;    //for address for jump instruction

//regrtMultiplexer
wire [4:0] regrtOw;
//immediateMultiplexer
wire [31:0] immMuloutw;
//ControlUnit  
wire [1:0] pcsrcw; 
wire [3:0] alucw;
wire shiftw,wregw,m2regw,aluimmw,sextw,regrtw,wmemw;  //Control Unit output
wire [31:0] qaw,qbw;             //regfile output
wire [31:0] muloutw;               //multiplexer output

//ALU   
wire [31:0] rw;  //ALU output
wire zw;         //ALU zero flag

//DataMem
wire [31:0] doMulw;

//Instantiate all modules
programCounter pc
(
//input
    .clk    (clk     ),
    .clrn   (clrn     ),
    .pcin   (pcinw    ),

//output
    .pcout  (pcoutw   ),
    .pc     (pc1      )
);
instructionFetch iF
(
//input
    .pc     (pc1   ),
//output
    .op     (opw    ),
    .func   (funcw  ),
    .rs     (rsw    ),
    .rt     (rtw    ),
    .rd     (rdw    ),
    .sa     (saw    ),
    .imm    (immw   ),
    .addr   (addrw  )
);    
regrtMultiplexer rM
(
//input
    .rd     (rdw    ),
    .rt     (rtw    ),
    .regrt  (regrtw ),
//output    
    .regrtO (regrtOw)
);
signextend se
(
    .sext    (sextw   ),
    .immin   (immw    ),
    .immout  (immoutw )
);
controlUnit cu
(
//input
    .op     (opw    ),
    .func   (funcw  ),
    .z      (zw     ),
//output
    .pcsrc  (pcsrcw ),
    .aluc   (alucw  ),
    .wreg   (wregw  ),
    .shift  (shiftw ),
    .wmem   (wmemw  ),
    .m2reg  (m2regw ),
    .sext   (sextw  ),
    .regrt  (regrtw ),
    .aluimm  (aluimmw)    
);
regfile rf
(
//input
    .clk    (clk    ),
    .clrn   (clrn   ),
    .rna    (rsw    ),
    .rnb    (rtw    ),
    .wn     (regrtOw),
    .d      (doMulw ),
    .we     (wregw  ),
//output
    .qa     (qaw    ),
    .qb     (qbw    ) 
 );
 immediateMultiplexer iM
 (
 //input
    .aluimm     (aluimmw),
    .qb         (qbw    ),
    .immoutI    (immoutw),
 //output
    .immMulout  (immMuloutw)
 );
 ShiftMultiplexer m1
 (
 //input
   .qa      (qaw    ),
   .sa      (saw    ),
   .shift   (shiftw ),
 //output
    .mulout (muloutw)
 );
 ALU alu
 (
 //input
    .aluc   (alucw      ),
    .a      (muloutw    ),
    .b      (immMuloutw ),
 //output
    .r      (rw     ),
    .z      (zw     )
 );
 DataMem DM
 (
 //input
    .a      (rw     ),
    .di     (qbw    ),
    .we     (wmemw  ),
    .m2reg  (m2regw ),
    .clk    (clk    ),
    .clrn   (clrn   ),
 //output
    .doMul  (doMulw )
 );
 multiplexer2 m2
 (
 //input
    .pcsrcI     (pcsrcw ),
    .pcoutI     (pcoutw ),
    .immout     (immoutw),
    .qa         (qaw    ),
    .addr       (addrw  ),
 //Output
    .pcinO      (pcinw  )
 );
```

endmodule

Answer (score 4):

modules in verilog are used to describe blocks of your model as well as hierarchy of those blocks. Every such module has a list of ports which defines inputs and outputs of the block.

blocks are instantiated inside other blocks to express hierarchy. They ports are connected in the module which instantiates other modules via variables defined in this parent module.

So, the idea is the following. supposedly you have 2 modules

```
module buf(input inp, output out);
    assign out = inp;
endmodule

module inv(input inp, output out);
     assign out = ~inp;
endmodule
```

supposedly you want to chain buffer and inverer. you need a top-level module which would instantiate and connect them

```
module top(input inp, output out);
    wire bufout;

    buf buf(.inp(inp), .out(bufout));
    inv inv(.inp(bufout), .out(out));
endmodule
```

So, in the above examle, both modules 'buf' and 'inv' are instantiated as 'buf' and 'inv' instances correspondingly. input 'inp' of 'buf' is connected to the 'inp' input signal of the 'top'. The output of it is connected to the 'bufout' wire defined inside the top module, which is also in input to the 'inv'. The output of 'inv' is connected to the output of the 'top'.

The rest depends on the number and types of the port of every module used int your model.